# Aggregate multiple max KO extend validations

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am using [ko extend validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Native-Rules) to validate,
Trying to do something like follows. ko.extend does not support multiple bindings for same type (max in this case) and it only adds first rule. 
Is there a way to conditionally pass the params with a function? or my only way out is writing a custom validation?

```
         myModel.prop2.extend({
            max: {
                onlyIf: function () {

                    var test = myModel.prop1() != undefined &&
                        myModel.prop1() !== "Percentage";
                    return test;
                },
                params: 100000
            }
        }).extend({
            max: {
                onlyIf: function() {
                    return myModel.prop1() != undefined &&
                        myModel.prop1() === "Percentage";
                },
                params: 100
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution,

```
.extend({
            validation: [{
                validator: function (val, someOtherVal) {
                    if (myModel.prop1()() !== "Percentage") {
                        return val < someOtherVal;
                    }
                    return true;
                },
                message: "Too big!!!!",
                params: 100000
            }]
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, what you are really trying to achieve. But the way that you tried is not valid way i think. So, you May have to use something like below,

[***Solution 1:***](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Custom-Validation-Rules)

***You can supply a validator or an array of them.***

```
var testObj = ko.observable(3).extend({
        validation: [{
            validator: function (val, someOtherVal) {
                return val === someOtherVal;
            },
            message: 'Must Equal 5',
            params: 5
        },{
            validator: function (val) {
                return val !== 8;
            },
            message: 'Can not be 8',
            params: 8
        }]
    });
```

[***Solution 2:***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696929/custom-knockout-validation-3-parameters)

```
ko.validation.rules['compareTo'] = {
    message: "Compare to",
    validator: function (val, params) {
        if (val === null || params.value() === null)
            return params.allowNull;
        switch (params.way) {
            case "<": return val < params.value();
            case "<=": return val <= params.value();
            case ">": return val > params.value();
            case ">=": return val >= params.value();
            default: throw new Error("params is not well defined");
        }
    }
}

myModel.prop2.extend({ compareTo: { 
                       message:"your message", 
                       params: { 
                                   way: ">=", 
                                   value: model.otherObs, 
                                   allowNull: true 
                       }, 
                       onlyIf: function () { /*your test*/ } 
                    }});
```

Hope this helps.,